# Stretching to Window sides from fixed point

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position

I'm having an issue with this design. At first, it looks simple: The left column is 25% wide and the right column is 75% wide. However, that's only within the center "container" which is 1140px wide. On larger screens, it gets much harder.

- The left column needs to stretch to the far left side of the window.
- The contents of the left column (but not it's background color) always stay within that 1140px container.
- The right column needs to stretch to the far right side of the window.
- The contents of the right column stretch to the right side of the window, and are not bound by the 1140px container.

[image: Diagram of what I need]

I'm using Bootstrap's grid system. But even breaking out of that and using absolute positioning, I don't know how to do this with only CSS, (no JS.)

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this layout might be close to what you're looking for. It makes use of `calc` to dynamically resize elements based on the container width:

Full page JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2ggyyjp1/1/embedded/result/

Live Demo (be sure to click Full Page!):

```css
.left {
    position: relative;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: black;
    width: calc(50% - 1140px * 0.25);
    float: left;
}

.left-content {
    width: 285px;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.right {
    height: 300px;
    background-color: blue;
    width: calc(50% + 1140px * 0.25);
    float: left;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">
    <div class="left-content">
        Text Contents Text Contents Text Contents Text Contents Text Contents Text Contents Text Contents Text Contents Text Contents
    </div>
</div>
<div class="right">
    Text Contents Text Contents Text Contents Text Contents Text Contents Text Contents Text Contents Text Contents Text Contents
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the time you put into this. Is there another method that you can suggest that doesn't use calc()? Lack of IE8 support might be an issue.

Comment: @TylerV. I tried a few ways of doing this without using `calc()`, but they were unsuccessful. To get IE8 to support calc though, you can [use this polyfill](https://github.com/closingtag/calc-polyfill). The polyfill should make this layout work fine on IE8.

Comment: Any way to do this without the fixed height? If .left-content has a dynamic height, then .left doesn't adjust.

Comment: Here's my quick crack at it: https://jsfiddle.net/4w4o6fLn/ You might need to ask another question though.

Comment: No, this is great. With some tweaks, it helped solve some other issues I was having with the above. Thanks!